# JQuery DatePicker: How to add a custom class

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need to apply a custom style to my datepicker but can't work out how to add a custom class to the datepicker. I am defining my date picker as follows:

```
            $("#From").datepicker({
                showOn: 'button',
                buttonImage: '/Content/images/icon-calendar.gif',
                buttonImageOnly: true
            }, $.datepicker.regional['en-GB']);
```

How do I add a custom class to the datepicker div?

```
<div class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all ui-helper-hidden-accessible MY_CLASS_GOES_HERE" id="ui-datepicker-div" style="position: absolute; top: 154px; left: 499px; z-index: 1; display: none;">
```

I know I can write:

`$("#ui-datepicker-div).addClass("MY_CLASS_GOES_HERE")`

..but can I rely on the datepicker always having an ID of "ui-datepicker-div"?? Is their a more elegant way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can rely on the ID being always the same, the same date picker is shared for multiple instances, so this *does* work reliably:

```
$("#ui-datepicker-div").addClass("MY_CLASS_GOES_HERE");
```

Comment: Thanks Nick. Thought as much but it's good to have it confirmed.

Comment: Not recommended. What if we only want add class to specific object, not all datepicker instance?

Comment: @GusDeCooL I agree with you but Guilherme answered the specific Q. Do you how I could assign an ID to a specific instance? Or even increment IDs? (e.g. the first instance gets #datepicker1, then #datepicker2, etc.)?